# netcat throughput low but iperf high

Tags: networking, bandwidth, netcat

I was testing the throughput between two pcs connected on the same router: one with 100mbps lan, the other with 54mbps wifi.

I tested both `netcat` and `iperf` and the throughtput I get is only 2.6mb/s.

What can be wrong? Shouldn't it be more?

Comment: Why does your title say something different than the body of this question? What does `iperf` tell you?

Comment: Duplicated on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/296539/netcat-throughput-low-but-iperf-high); closing here (if you want it to live here flag the SF version and ask them to migrate it)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek The question bodies are different (thanks to Caleb for spotting that): the SF version has different throughput for `nc` and `iperf`. George: did you make a mistake in one of your questions, or are these two different situations?

Comment: @Gilles I got the impression this one was just worded wrong; the title says "netcat throughput low but iperf high", which is the what the SF body says; the body here is just confusing

Answer (score 2):

Just because your wireless card is capable of 54mbs connections doesn't mean you are going to get that throughput. In particularly, it sounds like you have 802.11g which has an [Achilies heel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles_heal). As long as **every* wireless device it is talking to is also *g* it will go fast, but as soon as even one device that is only *b* speed capable, it has to use the lowest common denominator to talk to all devices.

You might try opening a terminal on the machine with wireless and running `iwconfig`. Look for the *Bit Rate=* field and see what speed you are actually connected at.

Comment: The question was crossposted on SF and is now closed here. Please consider reposting your answer on the [Server Fault version](http://serverfault.com/questions/296539/netcat-throughput-low-but-iperf-high).

Comment: @Gilles: I did just re-post, but note that the question over there is distinctly different and my answer isn't necessarily relevant. I still think it's something he needs to take into consideration, but it's more of a comment than an answer to his question as stated on SF.

Comment: Oh, so I see, well spotted. I suspect the U&L version has a correct title and wrong data in the body, but this requires clarification.